# When will soundcloud apps registration be back online?

Tags: api, soundcloud

I was building something, and planned to use the Soundcloud SDK - and I can't finish since app registration is closed. I've understood Soundcloud Dev answers questions here? Please let me know how long I have to wait before I can proceed - If I can't use SDK I'll have to spend a lot building something from the ground up..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question about the availability of a 3rd party service and needs to be addressed to their support team.

Comment: If you look at the Soundcloud for Developers site, they specifically ask that any questions be asked at Stackoverflow, where the developers hang out and answer questions... Should be relevant to all developers using / into Soundcloud SDK

Comment: Sound Cloud developers encourage you to ask technical, on topic questions here. We’re very aware that Sound Cloud directs questions here, but the questions still have to be on topic.

Comment: This *is* on-topic. It's a technical issue because I can't use their API to fullfill my client's needs and earn a living.

Comment: I have the same problem. Project on hold because it was based on their services - and this is the ONLY way I've found to direct a question to people in the know. I'd be very greatful if someone could help me answer this.

Comment: I feel the API being unavailable for an unknown amount of time is a very critical issue. Any information regarding when it will be available would be very relevant to me. Please do share if anyone finds anything!